# Angular 5 template drive form issue of dynamic rendering select field as one field changes

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

I have been facing some issue on angular project on my project. Currently I am using angular 5 and template driven form method. I have created sample here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzhncw

The second select field should be filled based on value select from first. The list shows fine but while I change second select field value and the again change first field the second field get extra blank field. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: This is expected behavior since the selected option is not contained in newly setted options.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i do that?? @Pengyy

Comment: You need to keep the selected option in your filtered result.

Comment: Make it select first value of the list when you change in first field or else it will show blank.

Answer (score 0):

As the value of second select field is base on first select field so after selecting value from second field when you change the first select field the related product changes. So once you change first field the second fill will show blank.